# Ubuntu won't boot; How do I uninstall the nvidia display driver?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I had Ubuntu 3.0.23 and installed manually the nVidia drivers 2 months ago. Now took the accumulated updates 3.0.26 and can't boot anymore. After the GRUB menu I get a black screen and a cursor. Is there a way to get into the system and remove the nVidia driver?. I have tried booting with both kernels and also the recovery mode but doesn't work.

Comment: Is there another OS you can boot using the driver/device (is it onboard or discrete)?

Comment: no, I have one drive dedicated to Ubuntu ... can't boot with none of the available kernels. Is there a command in grub I can run to login in "safe-mode" or anything alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I boot into **single user mode** from GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)

> 1. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use.
> 2. Press e to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.
> 3. Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to
>
>    ```
>    linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro quiet splash
>    initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
>    ```
> 4. Change the middle line in (3) by adding the kernel boot parameter single to the end of the line (i.e. after ro quiet splash).
>      For this example you would change
>
>    ```
>    6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro quiet splash
>    ```
>
>    to
>
>    ```
>    6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro quiet splash single
>    ```
> 5. Press either Ctrl+X or F10 to boot using these kernel options.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and doesn't work. I still get the same black screen and cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Following the details on [this page](http://www.tuxation.com/chrooting-into-a-linux-environment.html) I gained access to the broken Ubuntu installation and executing the following fixed the issue. After that I took out the LiveCD and rebooted and then I could login normally. I finally reinstalled the latest nVidia driver.

mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia

Comment: looks like the link is broken> :( What a shame